# what's the difference between "Files being created" and "Files created"

Tags: grammar

The sentence: `Files being created for an ongoing compaction or flush should not be removed`

What I know is that `created` is a past participle modifying `Files`, is `being` optional in this sentence?

**Update #1**

What's the difference of the three sentences below?

```
That the seas are being overfished has been known for years.
That the seas being overfished has been known for years.
That the seas overfished has been known for years.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files being created - Is referring to the file when it was in a state of being created. So once it's fully created, it's no longer relevant.
Files created - Refers to files that is fully created.

flow would go like "not created" -> "being created" -> "created"

So to sum up, in your specific sentence, "Files being created..." says they shouldn't be removed while they are being created, but after your done it's fine to get rid of them. Whereas if it had been "Files created...", then they should never be removed, even your done with the compaction / flush process (could be for logging purposes for instance, if you need a reason why that could make sense)

- "That the seas are being overfished has been known for years." the seas are the primary subject, and the fact they are being overfished has been known for years.
- "That the seas being overfished has been known for years." overfished
  becomes a defining part of the seas. So of all the seas, we're
  specifically talking about the overfished ones. So here what we have
  known for years are actually talking about the overfished seas, and
  not the fact they are overfished.
- "That the seas overfished has been known for years." False sentence, can still be understood, but as something like slang.

Comment: Thanks, could you please take a look at my second example, what's the difference between `the seas are being overfished` and `the seas being overfished`?

Comment: I don't think the second sentence makes sense in it's current state. It would either need to change to *sea's (sea is)* to talk about one particular sea, or it would  need *That* to be dropped and *has* to change to *have* (*The seas being overfished **have** been known for years*) to mean the ones being overfished have been in awareness.

Comment: As a stand alone sentence, I'll probably have to agree with you. I was reading it more as part of a larger paragraph that was not pasted. Even if there is nothing in the text hinting at it.

Mostly I was trying to explain the change in meaning when "are" was removed.